# Is a lowball salary then a part-time offer standard Japanese employment negotiations?

Tags: interviewing, negotiation, employment, culture, japan

I  have recently been interviewing for a remote position with a company based out of Tokyo, Japan. They are a fairly young start up, with one semi successful product currently out. They seem to be incredibly interested in hiring me. However, there seems to either be some cultural miscommunications or maybe just misunderstandings that I need help with.

They first offered a full time (remote) position to me, but it was substantially below what I could accept. I made this clear (politely) and had to decline. They said that was fine, and if their monetary situation changed they would let me know.

They came back several days later with the right amount of money (nearly double the original amount) but the offer specified it was only for a two month contract. I asked for clarification, and also said this was not long enough for me to consider leaving my stable job for.

This evening, I got another message asking if I would be interested in a part-time position, in conjunction with my full-time engineering job I already have. I have now told them that this won’t work, I need to have both good pay and a stable position to help their company reach its goals and for me to have a sane life. I recommended we have a meeting to better discuss what it is we are both looking for and need.

Is any of this normal? Do Japanese negotiations just look very different than other Western methods?

**TL;DR: I’ve been very clear with this company about what I need in a job, but they seem to not be understanding or are dodging things. Am I missing something?**

Details: I am an Electrical and Software Engineer located in the United States with a stable job and decent pay. I like this new company, and would be excited to work for them.

**Update: I was straightforward with the company and asked them what was the primary motivator behind their negotiations. They replied that their long term funds are unpredictable/limited, and they are trying to push out this big product in the next couple of months (hence the two month contract). After that they will be reassessing their full-time needs and may contact me. Thanks for all the feedback!**

Comment: Sounds more like standard startup than standard Japanese. They seem to be concerned about cash flow.

Comment: If they are concerned about cash flow, it's a very ethical concern for them to have (which I don't find surprising however I have little knowledge of japanese companies ethics). If they can't be sure they can pay you for more than 2 months, do you really want to take a job up anyway, even if they tell you it's permanent?

Comment: 2 months, renewable contract ?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

No, it is not a standard practice in Japan.

I think they are just a startup that can't afford to hire you on full-time at the price you are asking, so they are looking for alternatives.

As for the short-term contract, they may have specific tasks in mind they would like you to handle, that they can't handle with their current resources.

The part time offer was also probably geared to you taking over those specific tasks, with you keeping your day job so that your pay is at an acceptable level.

If you don't think you can work without a long-term full-time contract above a certain salary, then say that to them one more time, and if they can't make that offer, it may just be best to part ways.

Comment: This sounds like the most reasonable approach.  But if I may add one thing.
its possible the task they need handled wouldnt be a huge undertaking.  Perhaps ask them more about the things they would need completed in those two months.  it maybe something you can work on in your free/down time and make a nice little paycheck in the process.

Comment: I agree with @jesse, however, check your current contract for anything that may make that part-time illegal to take. For example, the contract might hav a clause stating that you can't work for another company in the same area while employed there.

Comment: Both good points - I have contacted them to clarify (just for curiosity's sake if anything) how many hours of part time they were considering.

Comment: Pay is generally lower in Japan as well. I see nothing but a slew of bright-eyed would-be candidates who roll in to the country expecting what they were getting in the US or Europe, only to get laid out when they realize that here, they're too expensive.

Comment: It's probably also worth bearing in mind that if the company is this worried about cash flow, there's a higher than normal risk of the company going broke. It's easy to forget about it if you've always worked for stable companies. They should compensate you for the risk you're taking, often with stock or some other sort of pay-out if the company does well.

Answer (score 29):

That is all about being a **startup**, possibly **not related to Japan** at all.

From the offers, it's pretty clear that they are **short on cash** for what they are planing to do. Probably an initial funding is running out. So it's not that they do not want to give you a normal full time contract, it's that it increases their risk significantly.

The risk is **to run out of money**. That may result in a bankruptcy, or in being bought (for little money) by some similar company. Both cases are not a good forecast for a stable job. In the second case chances are that the other company already has someone in your role. An additional red flag is that the current product is "semi successful", as that is probably an euphemism for **not successful at all**. That would explain being short on money. (My intuition is that they are dying, but still have hope.)

The conclusion is that you **can not assume a stable long term job** when working for them, completely independent from the contract you get. Even if they offer perfectly what you want, that does not change.

Comment: Your second point is definitely worth noting - that even if they were able to offer me a full time position, it still doesn't change that they may have cash flow issues now or in the future.

Comment: Call me crazy, but the *no way in hell* I would ever leave a stable job to go to a startup if the startup wasn't offering equity or a massively massive pay raise.

Comment: @Shane That's clearly crazy! There may be good reasons to join a startup. You may be bored in the stable job, and feel that you could go back - after leaving in a friendly way, or can assume you would find a new stable job. The startup may not provide a pay raise. But - provided you fit into the companies culture - you can have a huge influence in how the company grows. You do not longer work in a context defined by somebody  who may not be competent, or if he is, he might prefer different approaches than you. You will define the context. But need to learn to be competent yourself. Not boring.

Comment: Another reason (and one of my primary reasons) is for creativity's sake - the job I'm currently at is very compartmentalized, with no real room for personal creativity or influence. Whereas with a startup company (especially if it's smaller), there can be a lot more potential for individuality.

Comment: Ah. I wouldn't work somewhere under an incompetent manager, without any influence, where I was bored and uncreative. I mean, I've had jobs like that, but I was immediately looking for new work. In my mind jobs like that don't count as stable. I've found that medium or large sized companies that aren't specialized in your profession are great for this. Be the one graphic guy or web developer at the widget factory. Maybe I've just been rather lucky.

Comment: One reason to go to a start up is if you really believe in their product or what they are doing. Essentially, leaving the stability of your current job for "the greater good" instead of simply "a greater personal good" also makes sense to me.

Comment: @ConcernedHobbit Yes. Especially if it's smaller. And chances are you can choose yourself which less creative parts of your work you delegate - you automatically end up in a higher position, as long as you want to.

Comment: @Shane Yes, positively appreciating the the companies fundamental ideas - possibly a product or service - increases motivation and comfort of work massively.

Comment: If your own compensation isn't important, e.g. you have a big war chest, you could request shares in the company in lieu of pay. Fun fact, a guy in my city wrote an online quote system for a big insurance firm many years ago, they wouldn't pay him what he wanted so he negotiated that he'd get 5p a search. The stats showed it would be about £3000/year, so it solved their cash flow problem. The online system was one of the first 100% automated ones online and the company became HUGE, and this guy was literally raking in tens of thousands of pounds per *month* from it. Something to think about.

Comment: @SLC Yes, absolutely. I'd have an example at hand where it did not work out - which is not a reason not to do it again. It needs to be money you could loose without problem, the war chest. It's the same as any other way of investing in a young company. Simply a very risky investment, so risky that it is not available normally. A venture capital investor does the same, only that he gets lots of shares, and invests more money. Accepts to loose all the money in 1 of 10 cases or so - and earn a lot when it works out. (Easily financing the 9 other startups.)

Comment: @SLC Earning per transaction is great. But a fixed amount per transaction brilliant - for him. Not for the company - they will bring the costs per search  asymptotically down to something near zero in the long run. But need to pay  the 5p per transaction, so they have actual costs of approximately 5p and can not get below.

Answer (score 11):

*(The following is based on my limited personal experience (I am non-Japanese working in Japan for several years) and on what I gathered from talking to some Japanese friends, reading the Internet, etc. What I say below is true, but not universally true, and quite likely is not applicable to your situation. Still, it may help you to better understand their mentality... then again, their mentality may not be like that.)*

In Japan, you get hired fresh out of school/college/university and for the rest of your career. Your initial pay is *low*, but you get a regular unconditional raise (e. g. regardless of your performance), so after a decade it becomes reasonable, after two decades it may start getting high and keep growing. If you quit (which you wouldn't, because why would you?!) and get a new job, your initial pay is *low*, but... (see above). That is the tradition, which is now somewhat dead, but it is lingering in many companies (in the depths of their corporate schizophrenia): a new hire = fresh out of school/college/university, and should be paid accordingly. Yes, they are fully aware that you have this many years of relevant experience and whatnot, and at the same time, they kinda aren't. Regardless of the company's size, financial situation, etc. - I suspect, it is rather related to the attitude of the management (how modernized/westernized vs. traditional/japanized they are).

The limited time contracts is a somewhat new thing, getting more popular as the government pushes for more job security for the hired workers, and the companies push for those contracts which make it easier to get rid of you if need be. That's why they are paid better. Most people still prefer permanent contracts for their permanency. So the limited contracts are better paid, to encourage people to choose them. While the government is pushing towards making them essentially equal to permanent contracts (they made a law recently that your contract must be renewed unless the company can provide compelling reasons for being unable to extend it; they made another law that after ~5 years of working for the same company on such contracts you have a right to demand a permanent contract, etc.)

Comment: No, limited contracts (for dispatch workers) are poorly paid; you don't see so much of the Western idea of a freelancer. Here's [figures from 2007; page 27, fig 2-17](https://www.jil.go.jp/english/lsj/detailed/2011-2012/chapter2.pdf) shows about half the salary.

Comment: @Ken Y-N I don't know much about dispatch workers. I myself was given the choice a couple of times: a renewable 1 year contract or a permanent contract that pays about 30% less (don't remember the exact number, but something like that). With a 1 year contract you get more money right away, with a permanent contract you get more money eventually (move the black line on fig 2-17 up a couple notches, and that will more or less illustrate the tendency). Your mileage may wary.

Answer (score 3):

There are several kind of employment contracts in Japan.
It sounds like the tried to switch you from Seishain (permanent employee) to fixed term contract.

This is actually quite common and doesn't mean the company don't want to keep you in the long run.
This kind of contract usually comes with a higher pay due to the lower benefits.

However, others concern raised are very valid, and it doesn't mean that you should accept it: Only accept what you are confortable with.

Answer (score 1):

I partially agree to above answers, but I also think it is possibly some sort of probation period contract, so I wrote down my experience FYI in case you really like this job and need careful considerations.

I've worked for a Japanese MNC company before. What they did was providing me a 3-month contract initially, but also clearly stated inside contract that if my performance met their expectation, the contract would be updated into permanent within the probation period. And they actually updated it before the end of my second month.

Even if a candidate is strong, it is still possible that he cannot collaborate with team well. Most Japanese companies are very careful about this, and want to protect the existing loyal employees. Thus maybe they like you, but they are still not willing to take the risk by paying you much more than current ones.

What I suggest is that you carefully check the strength of this company, to make sure whether it is they "are not sure to hire you as permanent" or "cannot hire you as permanent". For a startup, if they cannot guarantee their own survival, how to promise yours?

Comment: Minor note: You mention _above_ answers - but if your answer gets upvoted to be higher scoring than other answers, then some answers will be _below_ your answer.  Better to maybe mention _other_ answers (or other answers _so far_)

Comment: While the probation period is pretty much set to 3 months, I don't know of any companies who would tell pepole they are only signing a 2-3 month contract. They will try to sell it as a full-time contract with a 3 month probation period.

Comment: @さりげない告白 Yes you are right, the possibility of what I said is very low. If their purpose is probation, they should clearly state it out. So most likely they only want a short-time/cheap employee to complete a certain task just as you already mentioned (unless this is a junior level startup that doesn't even know probation contract).